# Content Porter error while importing using LB URL

Tags: sites-9.5, content-porter, load-balancing

Using Tridion Sites 9.5.

We got a scaled-up CM servers setup and use a load balancer to distribute the load on CM servers.
When content porter is connected with LB URL for importing a package, the import process is often failing with the reason "invalid import package". If the URL of the individual CM instance is used in the content porter, the portering succeeds without any error. Hence there is no issue with the package itself. We don't prefer directly connecting with individual CM instance for security reasons.

It looks like content porter doesn't always maintain "sticky session" with the same CM instance while using the load balancer URL. The package is uploaded on one CM instance and but the sub-sequent processing of the package doesn't always run on the same CM instance which is resulting in "invalid import package".

Any fix for this issue? I see an [article](https://docs.rws.com/816112/534608/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/configuring-high-availability-storage-for-import-export-service-items) in SDL documentation that talks about high availability storage. Can the mentioned solution fix this issue? If so, can you please explain what will then happen on each CM instance? Will the import package be uploaded on each CM instance?

Comment: Can you try to use the IP address of the Load Balance and See if you still get the "invalid import package". also you can log all information Content Porter stores log files on the client, by default in the Content Porter\Logs to get more informarion

Answer (score 2):

For the scaled-out Load Balanced CME setup.

In the **Tridion.ContentManager.config** apart from enabling **useBinaryContentProvider=true** attribute, we also need to set this **binaryContentStorage** element and set its temporaryFolder attribute to a shared network location or you can also configure it to store the packages in the Amazon S3 bucket.

[Configuring a shared network temporary location for uploads to the Core Service](https://docs.rws.com/816112/694854/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/configuring-a-shared-network-temporary-location-for-uploads-to-the-core-service)

[Configuring a temporary location for uploads to the Core Service in the Amazon Cloud](https://docs.rws.com/816112/319778/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/configuring-a-temporary-location-for-uploads-to-the-core-service-in-the-amazon-cloud)

Both settings are required. hence you need to ensure the path to the uploaded binary will be accessible from any instance.

Also, Ensure stick sessions are enabled for the CME LB endpoint.

The reason is that the sticky sessions are enabled per the WCF client. In order to create a multimedia component (or TBB), two WCF clients are used: one for uploading a binary and another one for creating an item in TCM. These two clients may "stick" to different CM instances;

Comment: Thanks! Would like to understand a bit more on what then happens when a shared location is specified. Will the import process for the given package run on all CM nodes? Content porter gives the overview of what all items were created/updated at the end of import process. Will this overview then be the combined result of the import that happened on all CM nodes?